# Stopping a Client Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I use the following class the listen to around 20 udp ports. There is a problem though with this class in regard to how I stop it. Since I join the thread in the stop method I will have to wait for up to one second for each class to stop since recv has a timeout of one second. How would you recommend I solve this issue?

```
class UpdClient(threading.Thread):     

    def __init__(self,port):
        super(UpdClient, self).__init__()
        self.port = port
        self.finished = False
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind(('225.0.0.10', self.port))
        self.sock.settimeout(1)

    def run(self):
        while not self.finished:
            try:
                message = self.sock.recv(4096)
                print("*")
            except socket.timeout:
                continue

    def stop(self):
        self.finished = True
        if self.is_alive(): 
            self.join()
        print("Exiting :" + str(self.port))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one easy fix you can do to improve this: Split your `stop` function up into two separate functions, like this:

```
def stop(self):
    self.finished = True
    print("Stopping :" + str(self.port))

def wait(self):
    self.stop()
    if self.is_alive(): 
        self.join()
    print("Exiting :" + str(self.port))
```

And then do this:

```
for t in threads:
    t.stop()
for t in threads:
    t.wait()
```

With 20 threads, this should reduce your average stop time from ~10 seconds to ~1.1 seconds.

---

But if you want better than this, like a guarantee of 1 second, or an average time below 1 second, there's no good, easy way around this. Some possibly-bad and/or hard options include:

- `send` a message to your own socket, as suggested by [User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320237/user). If your code knows how to handle "garbage" messages, or if your protocol makes it simple to add a new message type that can be easily distinguished from the "real" messages, this should wake your threads up to shut them down very quickly.
- `close` the sockets out from under the client threads. On some platforms, this will cause the `recv` to fail immediately (you'll want an `except` to handle that, of course). On others, it will cause it to EOF immediately (which you already handle). There are some platforms where *neither* happens, and it just continues to block. So you'll really need to test on every platform you care about.<sup>*</sup>
- `self.daemon = True`. Then you can hard-kill all the threads just by exiting without joining them. With all the downsides that implies.
- Completely rewrite your app to use a single-threaded reactor or a multi-threaded proactor (ideally indirectly, through something like `asyncio`, `twisted`, or `gevent`…), instead of a thread per client.
- Change the 1-second waits to a loop over waits of no more than 100ms (or however long is acceptable for quit time).
- Just accept the 1-second time to quit.

---

<sub>* Off the top of my head, I believe Windows guarantees an error, Linux guarantees either an error or continuing to block but usually continues to block, BSD doesn't guarantee anything but usually continues to block, SysV doesn't guarantee anything but usually EOFs. But don't trust the top of my head; test the platforms you care about.</sub>

Comment: You should add the option of sending a byte to the socket and check `finished` after the `recv`.

Comment: @User: He's already checking `finished` after the `recv`. But you're right, for UDP, sending to yourself is often a good idea…

Answer (score -1):

Under Windows, add this:

```
def stop(self):
    self.sock.close()
    # ...
```

This creates the error:

```
OSError: [WinError 10004] A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall
```

in the Thread.

Comment: That's not guaranteed on every platform. In particular, Linux guarantees that it _won't_ happen. The thread may get an error, but usually will just keep waiting; it will never wake up and return EOF.

Comment: On WIndows I get `OSError: [WinError 10004] A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall`

Comment: So this doesn't make the socket return an empty string immediately on the only platform you've tested?

Comment: You know Linux, I know Windows, nice that we have a fruitful conversation.